# Pandas generating features vector with apply()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas

I have a data set with two features: class (int) and content (text).

Each row of content needs to be vectorized to a set of boolean features matching regexes. My vectorized function return a dictionary with 17 features like:

```
{'email':1, 'phone':0, 'curses':1,....}
```

Right now my code is this:

```
vectorized = data[['content', 'class']].join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        data.content.apply(lambda c: vectorize_content(c)).tolist(),
        dtype = int,
        index = data.index
    )
)
```

The desired result is:

```
class content            email phone curse ...
    0 'Hi'               0     0     0 ...
    1 'john@doe.com'     1     0     0 ...
```

In a real word dataset (~1mm rows) this takes ages!

My goal is to have a final data set with the class and each one of the boolean features as columns to feed a RandomForestClassifier.

I'm really new to sklearn/pandas so is very possible I'm doing something wrong.

Any tips on how to optimize this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could run faster with this code.

```
# Simulate function
def vectorize_content(c):
    return {'email':1, 'phone':0, 'curses':1}
# Simulate test data
data = pd.DataFrame({'class': [0,1], 'content': ['Hi','john@doe.com']})

vectorized = pd.concat([data, vectorized['content'].apply(lambda c: pd.Series(vectorize_content(c)))], axis=1)

# Result
   class       content  curses  email  phone
0      0            Hi       1      1      0
1      1  john@doe.com       1      1      0
```